# Is the grammar used in following sentence applicable to any similar situations?

Tags: sentence-structure

This is my sentence:

> How much a month is the rent for this house?

Similar situations

> How much a two nights is the rent for this room?
>   
> How much an every two nights is the rent for this room?
>   
> How much an hour is the rent for this bicycle?

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, only the last one works, because the other two have non-single nouns. This construction using "a" or "an" in place of "per" applies only to single-unit nouns, and is usually used to refer to an exchange of money.

> This hamburger costs $3.49 a pound.
>
> My rent is $250 a week.
>
> My salary is 2000 bucks a month.
>
> Bike rent is $10 an hour? How much is it a day?

If you want to ask how much two nights would cost, you can ask,

> How much a night is the rent for this room?

And then you multiply the answer by two. Alternatively,

> How much is two nights' rent for this room?

Answer (score 1):

That formulation with "a" (meaning "per") takes a time-noun in the singular: second, minute, hour, day, week, fortnight (British), month, year, decade, etc.

**How much a month does it cost?**

If you want to refer to an arbitrary period of time using a plural time noun:

**How much does it cost *every* three days?**

But there *every* doesn't mean *per* but refers to a recurrent event.